# Powershell content of the file

Tags: powershell-3.0

can you please help me with this one.

I need to create a script to check for a file (file name change everyday but it always starts with 'CA') in a folder  (c:\temp) and check if this file (the file has no extension) contains word 'error' in it and export results to log file

Comment: You should show us the code you have tried already. Please also remove the version tags and leave only the version youare actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$working_directory = "C:\test\"

$name_string = Get-ChildItem -Path $working_directory | select Name | Foreach { "{0}" -f $_.Name }

if ($name_string.Contains("CA")) 
{
$read_lines = Get-Content -Path $working_directory$name_string
foreach($item in $read_lines) 
{
    if($item.Contains("error"))
    {
        $item | Out-File -FilePath C:\test\$item    
    }
}
}
```

Read directory of file with "CA" if line in file contains "error" output that line to another file.

Answer (score 0):

sls error c:\temp\ca* | ac c:\temp\logfile.txt

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I am new here, howdy, yet I have intentionaly wrote an answer so short and used aliases in place of Select-String and Add-Content. My intention was to highlight the juxtaposition between the lenght and complexity of  my solution and the other one offered here. Also the qustion is rather basic and was even downvoted because of it and it seems to me a basic answer is just ok for it. 
Nevertheless my solution would work, I tested it, which I doubt could be said about the other one.